# How to produce answer key in exam class for multiple choice type of question?

Tags: environments, exam, answers

```
       \documentclass{exam}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{questions}
        \question Sample Question 1
        \begin{choices}
        \choice Option1
        \choice Option2
        \choice Option3
        \correctchoice Option4
        \end{choices}
        \question Sample Question 2
        \begin{choices}
        \choice Option1
        \choice Option2
        \correctchoice Option3
        \choice Option4
        \end{choices}
        \end{questions}
        \end{document}
```

The problem is to produce answerkey at the end of all questions in the format

```
1.Ans:(D)
2.Ans:(C)
```

and so on. This type of question has been asked few times but there is no satisfactory answer so far. It would be nice if someone can contribute to this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer describes two solutions. The first outputs the number/choice of the correct answer together with the answer, the second displays only the number (and collects several correct choices in a single line).

---

### List correct answers with their numbers

Mark the text of the correct answer (or rather, the part that should be displayed in the answer list) as follows.

```
\CorrectAnswer{... answer ...}
```

This command stores the answer together with the current question and choice number. You have to use it like

```
\begin{choices}
\choice Option1
\choice Option2
\choice Option3
\correctchoice \CorrectAnswer{Option4} % before and after \CorrectAnswer{} there may be other text which will appear only here
\end{choices}
```

Somewhere after the `questions` environment, the answers can be printed by

```
\printAnswers
```

The formatting of each answer is controlled by

```
\printAnswer{question number}{choice number}{answer}
```

You have to add the following definitions to your preamble.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\newcommand\Answers{} % Accumulates triples {{question number}{choice number}{answer}}
\newcommand\CorrectAnswer[1]{% {answer} % adds new triple to \Answers
  \xdef\Answers{\Answers{{\arabic{question}}{\Alph{choice}}{#1}}}%
  #1
}
\newcommand\printAnswer[3]{% {question number}{choice number}{answer} % format answer
  \par\noindent #1. Ans: (#2) #3\par
}
\newcommand\printAnswers{% do \printAnswer for every answer in \Answers
  \expandafter\printAnswersX\Answers{}%
}
\newcommand\printAnswersX[1]{% {{qu. number}{ch. number}{answer}} % auxilary command implementing loop
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\empty
    \let\tmp\relax
  \else
    \def\tmp{\printAnswer#1\printAnswersX}
  \fi
  \tmp  
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\newcommand\Answers{} % Accumulates triples {{question number}{choice number}{answer}}
\newcommand\CorrectAnswer[1]{% {answer} % adds new triple to \Answers
  \xdef\Answers{\Answers{{\arabic{question}}{\Alph{choice}}{#1}}}%
  #1
}
\newcommand\printAnswer[3]{% {question number}{choice number}{answer} % format answer
  \par\noindent #1. Ans: (#2) #3\par
}
\newcommand\printAnswers{% do \printAnswer for every answer in \Answers
  \expandafter\printAnswersX\Answers{}%
}
\newcommand\printAnswersX[1]{% {{qu. number}{ch. number}{answer}} % auxilary command implementing loop
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\empty
    \let\tmp\relax
  \else
    \def\tmp{\printAnswer#1\printAnswersX}
  \fi
  \tmp  
}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question Sample Question 1
  \begin{choices}
    \choice Option1
    \choice Option2
    \choice Option3
    \correctchoice \CorrectAnswer{Option4}
  \end{choices}
  \question Sample Question 2
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice Option1
    \choice Option2
    \correctchoice \CorrectAnswer{Option3}
    \choice Option4
  \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}

\printAnswers
\end{document}
```

---

### List only the choices

Add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\choices{\fi\do@choice@pageinfo}{\fi\CorrectAnswer\do@choice@pageinfo}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\oneparchoices{\fi\ifnum}{\fi\CorrectAnswer\ifnum}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand\Answers{} % Accumulates pairs {{question number}{choice number}}
\newcommand\CorrectAnswer{% {answer} % adds new pair to \Answers
  \xdef\Answers{\Answers{{\arabic{question}}{\Alph{choice}}}}%
}
\newcommand\printAnswer[2]{% {question number}{choice number}{answer} % format answer
  \ifnum#1=\lastQuestion
    , (#2)% additional correct answer
  \else
    \par\noindent #1. Ans: (#2)% First correct answer of question
  \fi
  \def\lastQuestion{#1}%  
}
\newcommand\printAnswers{% do \printAnswer for every answer in \Answers
  \def\lastQuestion{0}%
  \expandafter\printAnswersX\Answers{}%
  \par
}
\newcommand\printAnswersX[1]{% {{qu. number}{ch. number}} % auxilary command implementing loop
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\empty
    \let\tmp\relax
  \else
    \def\tmp{\printAnswer#1\printAnswersX}%
  \fi
  \tmp  
}
```

At the end of your document, the command `\printAnswers` will produce the list of answers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\choices{\fi\do@choice@pageinfo}{\fi\CorrectAnswer\do@choice@pageinfo}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\oneparchoices{\fi\ifnum}{\fi\CorrectAnswer\ifnum}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand\Answers{} % Accumulates pairs {{question number}{choice number}}
\newcommand\CorrectAnswer{% {answer} % adds new pair to \Answers
  \xdef\Answers{\Answers{{\arabic{question}}{\Alph{choice}}}}%
}
\newcommand\printAnswer[2]{% {question number}{choice number}{answer} % format answer
  \ifnum#1=\lastQuestion
    , (#2)% additional correct answer
  \else
    \par\noindent #1. Ans: (#2)% First correct answer of question
  \fi
  \def\lastQuestion{#1}%  
}
\newcommand\printAnswers{% do \printAnswer for every answer in \Answers
  \def\lastQuestion{0}%
  \expandafter\printAnswersX\Answers{}%
  \par
}
\newcommand\printAnswersX[1]{% {{qu. number}{ch. number}} % auxilary command implementing loop
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\empty
    \let\tmp\relax
  \else
    \def\tmp{\printAnswer#1\printAnswersX}%
  \fi
  \tmp  
}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question Sample Question 1
  \begin{choices}
    \choice Option1
    \choice Option2
    \choice Option3
    \correctchoice Option4
  \end{choices}
  \question Sample Question 2
  \begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice Option1
    \correctchoice Option2
    \correctchoice Option3
    \correctchoice Option4
  \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}

\printAnswers
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for. I just modified a line `\newcommand\Answer{ \par\noindent\arabic{question}. Ans: (\Alph{choice}) \par}` in order that all answers get printed to new line. For some strange reason answers of certain questions such as 6 and 7, 10 and 11 etc. are getting printed on same line. Also Is it possible to include the choice text as well such as `1.Ans:(D): Option4` and so on? How can code be modified in this case?

Comment: @user61681 See the extended answer. The price is that you have to mark the text that you want to include in the answer section.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precise reply. Hats off to you...

Comment: I found two difficulties in the old code which I am using: If two consecutive questions have same correct choice or option then both gets printed on same line. Secondly ( which I did not mention in the posted question) the code doesn't work if question has more than one correct choice. So would it be possible to modify old code (without printing  text of correct option), to print multiple correct choices. Thanks...

Comment: @user61681 I cannot reproduce your first problem: When I duplicate some question in the sample code above, it will be printed on separate lines. Is has to, since `\Answer` ends with `\par`.

Comment: The old solution was working fine until TeX distribution was updated. You may check that it is no longer working. What may be the reason? Which updates are causing the problem?

Comment: @user61681 The disadvantage of hacks using `\xpatch` is that they stop working if the code changes where the patch is supposed to replace a particular sequence by another one. I have updated the old solution (which now is actually the newest one) such that it works again.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can it be modified to include when multiple choices are correct. For example if option C and D are correct for second question, it may print `2. Ans: (C),(D)`. Right now it prints `2. Ans: (C)    2. Ans: (D)`

Comment: @user61681 I have updated the "old" solution (lower part of the answer) to collect correct choices of the same answer in one line.

Comment: Thanks once again. It works great!!!

Comment: The code does not work when you have oneparchoices. How to modify this code?

Comment: @srini I have expanded my answer. If this does not do what you need, I suggest to ask a new question and to add a small sample code that shows what you need.